# Are there any rules for when a method changes an object "in place" or returns a new object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, methods

I'm practicing for my exam and there are always questions asking whether a method changes an object in place or creates a new object. I wonder if there are any general rules applied to this or if I just have to memorise the outcome for different methods?

The examples from my exam are:

```
s = 'horse'
s.upper()
print(s)
```

this will generate `horse` and not `HORSE`, and thereby s is not changed by `.upper`, however

```
l = [1, 3, 2]
l.sort()
print(l)
```

will generate `[1, 2, 3]` and not `[1, 3, 2]`, and thereby l is changed by `.sort`

Are there any ways to differentiate between these?

Comment: Besides remembering that strings are *immutable* and lists are *mutable*…? Not really. Hint: Python has an explicit philosophy specifically about sorting: the `.sort` method sorts *in place* and *returns `None`*, explicitly to remind people that it sorts in place; besides that there's `sorted()`, which explicitly returns a copy. But that doesn't help you generally.

Comment: You need to assign `s.upper()` back to `s`. Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real generic ways to remember this. You need to remember on an individual basis. You can generally remember that strings are *immutable* and *never* change. And you can specifically remember that the `.sort` method explicitly returns `None` to remind people that it sorts in place, and that you need to use the `sorted()` function if you want a copy instead. But those are specific to strings and sorting, knowing this doesn't help you to generalise at all.

Generally speaking, such knowledge simply accumulates with usage. In practical everyday programming, nobody needs to know this by heart, since you'll always be thumping the documentation while you're coding and/or you'll try small snippets on the interactive command line to confirm their workings. Learning this by rote for a test has no practical purpose in later use; likely you're supposed to remember the few types and functions that were explicitly mentioned in your lessons, if you're presented with a heretofore unknown type, your guess will be as good as mine.

Comment: Good answer. I just wanted to add that the popular `pandas` package tends to be more explicit about it, with a keyword argument called `inplace` that sometimes appears and get be set to `True` or `False`.